# how to enable scrolling when ListView widget reach at top in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

To explain what I want I have created a simple demo file

Here I have 4 container,

What I want is, when I scroll up ,all three container( RED, GREEN and listview) should be scrolled up and when listview reach at top (below welcome container) its scrolling should be start...

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  List<String> mydata = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //this welcome container should be fixed at top
            Container(height: 50, child: Center(child: Text('Welcome'))),
            Container(
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: mydata.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(mydata[index]),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(),
                      );
                    }))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the `itemCount` by two.

```dart
body: SafeArea(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(height: 50, child: Center(child: Text('Welcome'))),
      Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: mydata.length + 2,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (index == 0) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  );
                }
                if (index == 1) { // you can just merge it with if like `index<2`, then use condition
                  return Container(
                    height: 200,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  );
                }
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(mydata[index - 2]),
                  leading: CircleAvatar(),
                );
              }))
    ],
  ),
),
```

Also I will suggest you to check `CustomScrolView`.

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted logical way...

Comment: Glad to help, you can check CustomScrolView which will provide more features.

Comment: hi..can u check my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75209968/how-to-select-multiple-items-while-using-sticky-grouplist-in-flutter